# How can I get my Trigger to work in MySQL 8.0?

Tags: mysql, mysql-8.0

The following trigger works perfectly well in MySQL 5.7. I have used it extensively.

```
DELIMITER $$

#
# FUNCTIONS
#
-- @_path
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `path`$$
CREATE DEFINER=CURRENT_USER FUNCTION path(id INT unsigned, level BOOLEAN) RETURNS VARCHAR(3000)
    DETERMINISTIC
    BEGIN
        ...
    END $$

#
# TRIGGERS
#
-- @_root - INSERT MATERIALIZED PATH & RANK
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS tx_tt_domain_model_root_Bi_0;
CREATE TRIGGER tx_tt_domain_model_root_Bi_0 BEFORE INSERT ON tx_tt_domain_model_root
    FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
        SET @_relation=if(NEW.relation,path(NEW.relation,false),null);
        SET @_role=if(NEW.role,path(NEW.role,false),null);
        ...
    END $$

...

DELIMITER ;
```

After upgrading to MySQL 8.0, the trigger throws the following error when attempting to load it:

```
[2022-06-24 13:36:05] [42000][1064] You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(NEW.relation,false),null);
[2022-06-24 13:36:05]       SET @_role=if(NEW.role,path(NEW.role,false),null)' at line 8
```

EDIT; I created a fresh install of MySQL 8.0 and loaded it with all the necessary tables. Am now loading stored procedures and triggers and getting stuck while loading the trigger above.

Perhaps am missing something in plain sight or haven't quite understood how MySQL 8 really works or something else. What am I doing wrong? Please help.

Comment: Not familiar with the path function what does that do? and do you have a link for it?

Comment: I think that `path` is user-defined function... and you forget to copy it to new server. or maybe this function contains some syntax which was removed in 8.0, and the function was not upgraded but removed during upgrade.

Comment: @P.Salmon The path function is a custom function that runs through the database records and creates a path from each record's ancestry chain to that particular record. The path is then stored in a path field in the trigger table upon record insertion.

Comment: @Akina, yes it is a custom function and it is inserted before the trigger. It is already loaded. Just checked.

Comment: `path` is non-reserved keyword starting from version 8.0.4. If the function is present in the database then I recommend you to rename it. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html#keywords-8-0-detailed-P

Comment: Does variables ` @_relation` and ` @_role` have declare statement ?

Comment: @Kadet These are user-defined variables which does not need and even cannot be declared (rather than local variables).

Answer (score 0):

A big thank you to [Akina](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10138734/akina) for pointing out that `path` is actually a ***non-reserved*** keyword introduce in [MySQL 8.0.4](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html#keywords-8-0-detailed-P).

Just renamed the custom function to `create_path` and now loads without complaining.